# Memory error issue when running scipy interpolation (interp1d)

Tags: python, memory, scipy, interpolation

I have tried to run scipy 1d-interpolation (interp1d) with various interpolation methods. Data is an array with 525600 numbers. When I ran it with simpler methods such as 'linear', 'nearest' or 'zero', it worked fine, but when I used 'cubic' or 'quadratic', it resulted 'memory error as below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "inter_comp.py", line 37, in <module>
interp = interp1d(indices[not_nan], B[not_nan], bounds_error=False,fill_value=0.,  kind = 'cubic')
File "/lustre/work/apps/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-   packages/scipy/interpolate/interpolate.py", line 476, in __init__
self._spline = splmake(self.x, self._y, order=order)
File "/lustre/work/apps/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/interpolate.py", line 2356, in splmake
B = _fitpack._bsplmat(order, xk)
MemoryError
```

My code is as below:

```
filn1 = "/lustre/work/hwon/PAPER2/Data/BAO_NEW/1year_New/BAO010_2013_WS_N.txt"

B = np.genfromtxt(filn1,delimiter="",usecols=0,dtype=None)
not_nan = np.logical_not(np.isnan(B))
indices = np.arange(len(B))
interp = interp1d(indices[not_nan], B[not_nan], bounds_error=False, fill_value=0.,  kind = 'cubic')
p1 = interp(indices)
```

I am not sure whether is the problem of the computing platform which I used or of the way to handle the data or of the coding.

Would you please give me any idea to sort this problem out?

Thank you,
Isaac

Comment: Without having experiece, this looks like normal behaviour to me due to the increased complexity of the task if it's not linear. I would reduce the data, compare memory usage of linear vs. cubic; increase the data a bit, compare again. From this you might get some idea of the internal algorithmic complexity (or more important: memory-complexity). Maybe subsampling is also a valid approach for your final interpolation (if you can't handle all the data, just use a subset). Sadly there seems to be not much information about the internals in the docs :-/.

Comment: @sascha: Thank you for the suggestion, for sure I will try shorter data comparing cubic/quadratic and linear.

Comment: @sascha: However, I need to use this whole data, not reduced one. So, I am looking for the way to use the whole array of numbers using cubic and quadratic interpolation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spline interpolation in interp1d uses full matrices. Better use splev/splrep combo, UnivariateSpline, or CubicSpline (to be available in the future scipy version).

**EDIT**: This answer is obsolete as of scipy 0.19.0 and above, where `interp1d` no longer uses full matrices.